# Data ownership and reference in MVVM (specifically C++/WinRT, UWP, WinUI)

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, uwp, c++-winrt, winui-3

I've set up a very simple (Universal Windows) App in C++/WinRT.
It's just `App <- MainPage <- DataViewModel <- Data` for now.
`MainPage` has some Sliders etc. which are bound (`x:Bind`) to `DataViewModel`, which contains an instance of `Data`. Working fine so far.

**However, the `Data` is a *member* of `DataViewModel`. This seems to be an obvious code smell.** Data should not be "owned" by the GUI. All Examples/Samples I've come across seem to be set up like this, though.

I also want to run a background thread (pure C++ code) that works with one and the same instance of `Data`.

**The question: Who "owns" `Data`. How do I connect things? How to pass the reference?**

My best idea so far: The `App` class itself should just own the one instance of `Data`. The `MainPage` ctor should take a `Data&` and pass it on to the ctor of `DataViewModel`. However, I don't seem to be able to write a custom ctor for `MainPage`, because there's generated code involved.

**Just pointing me to well coded Sample App would also be appreciated.**

Comment: That largely depends on what `Data` actually is. In case it is the [projected type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#what-do-the-projected-type-and-the-implementation-type-mean-) of a Windows Runtime type, then that is really a shared reference with the same semantics as a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Having the UI own a shared pointer isn't entirely bad. So long as you make sure to not introduce any reference cycles. Weak references help with that.

Comment: Take `Data` to be just a simple C++ class.

Comment: For anything trivial, just place all your data into the [`Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application) class. It has a static member [`Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.current#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_Current) member, so you can get to it from anywhere. You can then introduce accessors to individual data items, or the model as a whole. There's no need to pass the model down. Though this question should probably be asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Accessing a global variable (or static member of App) from a viewmodel just CANNOT be the preferred way to set things up. What is a clean way? That is my question. How do viewmodels access data if they do not own it!? (or is there a good reason that they should own it? If so, how would the other code  access it?)

Comment: Ownership really only matters when non-static lifetimes are involved. If `Data` represents data with static lifetime then there's nothing inherently wrong with exposing it through a static `App` class member. Otherwise have your view models "own" a shared reference (`std::shared_ptr` or `winrt::com_ptr`), passed into the constructors. As for sample code, there's the [Photo Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/photo-editor-sample) sample. You can have a look and see whether it translates to your situation and how it handles data.

Comment: As for the "Photo Editor": Again, MainPage loads and owns those photos. Which I find quite questionable. Please do your code review on that sample ;-)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place for code reviews. If you do take this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) make sure to explain *"obvious code smells"*, what's *"questionable"*, and describe the concrete problems you wish to solve. As for the Photo Editor sample: If you look closely, `MainPage` owns an `IVector<IInspectable>`. That's a shared reference to a container (interface) holding shared references, ultimately what you find acceptable with the proposition of passing a `Data&` around. Except that it doesn't break in a heavily async framework (unlike C++ references).

Comment: We might finally be getting somewhere after all this `<IAmbiguous, IBeatAroundTheBush>`. Owning interfaces is different from owning data. If you could make a point why this is the way to go... that would probably answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

[IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) (in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556575/data-ownership-and-reference-in-mvvm-specifically-c-winrt-uwp-winui#comment124736533_70556575) above) makes a noteworthy point: "Ownership really only matters when non-static lifetimes are involved. If Data represents data with static lifetime then there's nothing inherently wrong with exposing it through a static App class member."

In this vein, don't limit your thinking of `Data` (i.e., the model) to just  object(s) which some other object owns. The model should be thought of as a wholly independent component.

Let me approach this notion from another angle. Most people will readily describe MVVM as three independent "layers" or "components" or what have you, wherein the model "doesn't care" about the view model, which in turn "doesn't care" about the view.******   In code (as you have seen yourself), you're probably going to find some clear cut ownership patterns to reflect that basic premise. For example, if we're following the the "view-first" approach like the Microsoft samples, you'll start with your App object, which owns an instance of a view object, which in turn instantiates a view model instance.

But the key to MVVM is not who owns whom, it's the relationships between those layers. If you wanted to, you could write a program where, say, the views and view models were all static members of the App class and still have a (conceptually) textbook MVVM structure once everything is hooked up. From that perspective, it doesn't matter where ownership resides.

Now, the thing about Microsoft samples like the Photo Editor is that ultimately they're just demonstrations of how things can work, not a treatise on design patterns. Consider when your data is coming from a database or a web service. Where do you draw the conceptual line between model and view model? The question may sound pedantic, but the way you evaluate these things influences your design decisions.

Which brings me back to your specific question. If it seems like code smell to you when examples you find online stick the model data any old place, you're not wrong. In "real life," the model can be an entire API, not just one illustrative class. You'll potentially have an elaborate subsystem delivering data to you that depends on services completely separate from your application. Or it might be an opaque third-party API that you're calling into via global functions, etc. Just remember that the key isn't "ownership," it's (the conceptual) "relationship." *******

****** As a side note, you mention `Data` being a member of `DataViewModel` and describe this as `Data` being "'owned' *by the GUI*." Ideally, the view model should have no inherent ties to the UI, just application logic. Don't think of it as an extension of UI functionality.

******* But please don't take this post to imply that the actual implementation of the MVVM paradigm isn't important. That's true of any design pattern. The exact form that implementation takes depends on the specific application and whatever your boss wants you to do. All I'm saying is, don't get hung up on ownership. :)

Comment: Thx for elaborating. However the problem still persists: How do I make my viewmodels aware of the Data if they don‘t own it (i.e. it is a static variable in App)

Comment: @non-user38741 If you're looking for an exact code sample, it'd be misleading to give you one. There's all different ways to do it. That's why my last paragraph lists generalized examples. But to give you an example, right now I'm working on a project that's using an API that retrieves items from a database. That API exposes everything through static functions. So all that's needed to make the view model(s) aware of the data is an #include directive. Nothing "owns" that model data, per se, it has static storage duration and is always available throughout the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Thx man (or rather Dan)! API is obviously the general way to go. I guess I got a bit too obsessed with OOP.

Comment: @non-user38741 You're very welcome. And really, it's not entirely obvious from examples, imo. If there's some way you'd like for me to improve my answer for you to accept it, let me know!